# Can I power an (extended) LED stripe from both ends simultaneously?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, led-strip

[image]
I have a 5 meter WS2812B (5V) LED stripe which I need to extend with another 100cm. I want to power both stripes using a 60W sitched-mode power supply, however I have read that you should not daisy chain more then 5m because the stripes are not designed for the additional current.
How should I do this?

1. Connect Vcc, GND and Data on the extension point and then power the stripe from both ends simultaneously using the same power supply. Will this balance the current on both sides or will it short circuit?
2. Only connect Data on the extension point and separately connect the second stripe to the power supply.

Comment: I would only connect data and ground, but not 5V across the midpoint.  You have to have the grounds connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with tcrosley in the comment above.

This is a common problem with distributed lighting. My solution is to calculate the maximum current at periodic places within the lighting strip. Use that current value and whatever maximum voltage drop that you can tolerate to determine the maximum resistance allowable between the power supply and the LED strip.

Remember that you are feeding current both ways on the strip when determining the current.

Then run two heavy-gauge conductors underneath the LED strip and periodically make connections from the heavy wires to the strip. The wire size is determined by the distance and the maximum allowable voltage drop.

Note that you can stagger or alternate the connections. That is - connect only the Ground at one location, connect only the power at the next location. This can help make things both easier and neater than trying to make both connections at the same location.

Feed both ends of the heavy conductors if needed. This can be separate power supplies.

Comment: So basically I should do what tcrosley said (daisy chain GND & Data) but try to evenly balance Vcc across the stripe? Also option 1 is then not possible?

Comment: Your option 1 is completely acceptable. If you have the ability to connect both ends of the strip to the same power supply, do so. I'm assuming that the strip is one continuous string where all individual sections are connected together. That means that both the power and ground conductors are contiguous.

Comment: @DwayneReid is there any benefit from powering both ends? I'm planning to make a LED panel which is cut into  16 strips of 250cm in length so thinking should I power both ends of each of them?

Comment: The benefit of feeding both ends of the strip is that voltage drop along the strip is reduced by a factor of 4. Why 4? Half the current for the strip goes into each end. That current has to reach only half way along the strip. Half of a half is one quarter.